# Scan specific packages for Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to use AOP into an existing (big) Spring project. The thing is that I don't want Spring to create proxies for all the objects in the ApplicationContext, mainly for performance but also because there are final classes that I cannot modify.

I've tried to make Spring search only inside "com.foo.bar.*" by defining the following aspect:

```
com.baz.MyAspect

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAspect.class);

    @Before("within(com.foo.bar.*) && " +
        "execution(* com.foo.bar.MyController.handleRequest(..))")
    public void getData() {
        // Nothing yet
    }
}
```

And I've added this lines to the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans ...>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean id="myAspect" class="com.baz.MyAspect"/>
</beans>
```

But when I run the app, I get the following Exception:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.foobar.FinalController]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.foobar.FinalController
```

So it seems that Spring is scanning packages other than the ones defined in the within expression. I would like to know whether there is a way to specify the packages to be scanned or any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question completely, Spring does not create proxies for everything, only for the beans which match the pointcut, so you can state your pointcut with the package prefix and only those beans should get proxied.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can define your point cut like this

the execution of any method defined in the bar package or a sub-package:

execution(* com.foo.bar..*.*(..)) [click here for detail](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/aop.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am defining the point cut, but Spring is trying to create proxies of classes in other packages. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: according to exception you are trying to create a proxy object for final class. why did u declare a controller final?